# How to pass variable with constant value in Json postman request?

Tags: json, postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-pre-request-script

`{{partnerOrderId}}`- is Prerequest script through created value and considering this value as - `23457891`

I have created partnerOrderId using this code:

```
const partnerOrderId = Math.floor((Math.random()*333333333))
pm.globals.set("partnerOrderId", partnerOrderId);
```

`-partner2345-`   -this value is constant.

I have to pass value as  `23457891-partner2345-23457891`

I tried below code in post man. But its showing error.

```
  "partnerOrderNumber": {{partnerOrderId}}+\"-partner2345-\"+{{partnerOrderId}},
```

Comment: I've provided an answer based on what I _think_ the question is but the details you have provided, don't really make any sense so I would suggest re-writing the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you add something like this to the `Pre-Request Script` to create the variable:

```
let partnerOrderNumber = `${pm.globals.get('partnerOrderId')}-partner2345-${pm.globals.get('partnerOrderId')}

pm.globals.set('partnerOrderNumber', partnerOrderNumber)
```

[image: Postman]

You will be able to use this variable in the `Request Body` like this:

```
"partnerOrderNumber": {{partnerOrderNumber}}
```

Comment: Did that help with the problem Ryan?